# Invoke a macro in Outlook from a button in email message

Tags: vba, outlook

How to invoke a macro in Outlook from a button in email message?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You would need to use an Outlook custom form, with a [OlkCommandButton Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177074.aspx).

**Updated with new links:**

- [Controls on Outlook Forms](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=32)
- [Tutorial: Creating and distributing custom forms with Outlook](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/tutorial-creating-and-distributing-custom-forms-with-outlook/)
- [Frequently asked questions about Microsoft Forms](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/frequently-asked-questions-about-microsoft-forms-495c4242-6102-40a0-add8-df05ed6af61c)

Related:

- [How to use option buttons on an Outlook custom form](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290652)
- [Tutorial: Creating and distributing custom forms with Outlook](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/tutorial-creating-and-distributing-custom-forms-with-outlook-HA001210610.aspx)
- [Frequently asked questions about custom forms and Outlook solutions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/146636)

Comment: I have created the form which contains my own buttons and i am even able to assign the macro for those buttons. 


Now if i send an email from my custom application how to make the outlook to use this custom form. Can you help me in this .......

Comment: All three reference links are dead.